# Deixar imagens inline numa div overflow

Tags: css, html5

Bom, eu estou tentando fazer um "slider" com o uso do overflow do css, porém estou tendo problemas porque não consigo alinhar as imagens.
Quando dou um width 100% na div ove
As imagens ficam em 2 colunas uma em baixo da outra, e o que eu quero é que elas ficassem alinhadas

(Coloquei imagem pois o html bugou)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia usar flexbox na div `.ove`, porque aí as imagens ficaram alinhadas uma ao lado da outra. Basta colocar `display: flex` na div `.ove`:

```css
.ove{
   width: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   display: flex; /* flexbox */
}

.ove img{
   width: 600px;
   /* display: inline-block;
   position: relative; */
   height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ove">
   <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
   <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
   <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
   <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">

   <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
   <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
   <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
   <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
</div>
```

As propriedades que você aplicou nas imagens, `display: inline-block;` e `position: relative;` são irrelevantes. As imagens já são `inline` por padrão, e alterar para `inline-block` não vai fazer diferença.